# Three.js - release memory

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I use the built-in shape extrusion function to extrude a shape along a spline.
I create a new mesh everytime I move the nodes of the spline. But this 
way my RAM is full very fast. Everytime I create a new mesh I delete the
old one with

```
scene.__removeObject(mesh);
```

but it doesn't release the used memory. I tested Firefox Nightly and Chrome and both crash if the memory is full.

I searched for a general WebGL feature and for Three.js related solution but didn't find anything.

Maybe someone with more WebGL / Three.js knowledge can give me a hint.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you're not referencing the javascript mesh object anywhere else, so that the garbage collector can delete it.